# Thread implementation with ExecutorService gives Out of memory error after a period of time

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using ExecutorService for implementing threads for UDP socket listeners.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        if (listenerSet != null) {
            for (Listener listener : listenerSet.getListeners()) {
                ListenerThread listenerThread = new ListenerThread();
                listenerThread.setListener(listener);
                service.submit(listenerThread);
            }

        }
         service.shutdown();
```

ListenerThread class is an implementation of Runnable interface. listenerSet can have maximum 3 listeners.

This works fine for an amount of time and gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError after that. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Well you are creating a `butt` ton of threads some where... It's very rare that you get an `OutofMemory` error. Do you have that code within an inifinte loop or something?

Comment: Can you post the code of Listener thread too? If you need more control on   thread pool execution, you can work with ThreadPoolExectutor, set the bounded queue size & add RejectionHandler code.

Comment: Inside that I am using a UDP scoket listener which listens to some port and each packet received is processed in a different thread.